# Looking for big, complex sample data

Tags: bigdata, graph-databases, sample-data

I want to benchmark some (graph) databases and looking for some big, complex datasets. The dataset should have a size between 2 TB and 5 TB. Do you know any sample datasets (maybe open government or science data) which fullfills these criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These should fit your requirements

- The [1000 Genomes](http://www.1000genomes.org/ftpsearch/) project makes 260 TB of human genome data available
- The [Internet Archive](http://blog.archive.org/2012/10/26/80-terabytes-of-archived-web-crawl-data-available-for-research/) is making an 80 TB web crawl available for research
- The TREC conference made the [ClueWeb09](http://lemurproject.org/clueweb09.php/) dataset available a few years back. You'll have to sign an agreement and pay a nontrivial fee (up to $610) to cover the sneakernet data transfer. The data is about 5 TB compressed.
- [ClueWeb12](http://lemurproject.org/clueweb12/) is now available, as are the Freebase annotations, FACC1
- CNetS at Indiana University makes a 2.5 TB [click dataset](http://cnets.indiana.edu/groups/nan/webtraffic/click-dataset/) available
- ICWSM made a large corpus of blog posts available for their [2011 conference](http://www.icwsm.org/2011/data.php). You'll have to register (an actual form, not an online form), but it's free. It's about 2.1 TB compressed.
- The Proteome Commons makes several large datasets available. The largest, the Personal [Genome Project](https://proteomecommons.org/data), is 1.1 TB in size.

There are several others over 100 GB in size.